# No tasks defined on GraphQLLocust even with correct "tasks" syntax

Tags: python, graphql, locust

I'm using locust version: 1.5.3; a locust-graphql-client: https://github.com/DesignrKnight/locust-graphql-client

My aim is to make graphql calls using locust for assessing performance.
I have below locust code:

```
from locust import HttpUser, TaskSet, task
from locustgraphqlclient import GraphQLLocust


class UserBehavior(TaskSet):
    def on_start(self):
        """ on_start is called when a Locust start before any task is scheduled """
        self.login()

    def on_stop(self):
        """ on_stop is called when the TaskSet is stopping """
        self.logout()

    def login(self):
        query = '''
        mutation login($username: String!, $password: String!) {
          login(username: $username, password: $password) {
            access_token
          }
        }'''
        variables = {
            'username': 'gm',
            'password': 'centric8'
        }
        result = self.client.execute("login", query, variables)

        # Inject the Access Token in the Client, so subsequent requests can be made
        self.client.inject_token(result['data']['login']['access_token'])

    def logout(self):
        # Reset the Access Token in the Client, so no subsequent requests can be made
        self.client.inject_token('')

    @task(2)
    def index(self):
        query = '''
                    query products {
                      products {
                        id
                        name
                        image
                      }
                    }'''
        result = self.client.execute("products", query)

    @task(1)
    def profile(self):
        query = '''
                    query me {
                      me {
                        id
                        username
                        firstName
                        lastName                    
                      }
                    }'''
        result = self.client.execute("me", query)


class WebsiteUser(GraphQLLocust):
    tasks = [UserBehavior]
    min_wait = 5000
    max_wait = 9000
```

I get the error as below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 285, in run
    self.schedule_task(self.get_next_task())
  File "/~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 417, in get_next_task
    raise Exception(
Exception: No tasks defined on GraphQLLocust. use the @task decorator or set the tasks property of the User (or mark it as abstract = True if you only intend to subclass it)
```

As you can see I used correct syntax for tasks as mentioned here: [locust 0.9 to 1.3 Exception: No tasks defined. use the @task decorator or set the tasks property of the User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64336473/locust-0-9-to-1-3-exception-no-tasks-defined-use-the-task-decorator-or-set-th) and here https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/1537

Is it a problem with the locust graphql client I'm using? or is it something in the code?
Also are there any standard clients I can use for graphql in locust?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locust is trying to instantiate your base class. Mark the GraphQLLocust class abstract by setting abstract = True.

Comment: Thanks, it was the problem. I have added abstract=True in the imported library and it worked.